# How do VMs in a Hyper V R2 cluster respond in the event that the node of the cluster the VM was running on fails?

Tags: windows-server-2008, virtualization, hyper-v, cluster, hyper-v-server-2008-r2

How do VMs in a Hyper V R2 cluster respond in the event that the node of the cluster the VM was running on fails?

Does the VM automatically restart on another node and to the VM it is just like someone pulled out the power cords of a server and then turned it back on again or does it do something more or less than this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does the VM automatically restart on
>   another node and to the VM it is just
>   like someone pulled out the power
>   cords of a server and then turned it
>   back on

Pretty much. The failed vms start on other nodes of the cluster

Comment: Does it even restart?  I thought the VM would simply "transfer" (while still running) to one of the other nodes in the cluster.

Comment: @Joe, if the node fails to the point where Hyper-V is no longer responding then it's like pulling the plug. If the node becomes degraded (some hardware fails but hyper-v is still responding) it will live migrate the VMs to other nodes.

Comment: Exactly. Note that live migrate assumes that there still is something to migrate. If a node fails (the more common scenario).... there is no host to migrate from. Restarting the instance is all that can be done.

Comment: Just to confirm, the VM will automatically start on the other node of the cluster or I will have to manually start the VM?

Comment: Depends how things are congfigured, but in a normal congirutation the item would be started on another machine IF another machine is available with enough ressources (mostly memory, obviously).